# Fingerprinting using python module called pybel

Tags: python, fingerprint, fingerprinting, openbabel, pybel

I want to get fingerprints using smiles of compounds. I did but the problem is I want to get in a higher bit and a list format so I can calculate the length of lists. In this case I just get classes. Any solution in python using pybel? I did this but when I write `len(fps[0])` I get an error

```
import pybel
smiles = ['CCCC', 'CCCN']
mols = [pybel.readstring("smi", x) for x in smiles]
fps = [x.calcfp() for x in mols]
print fps[0]
```

Comment: What error do you get? Don't you just need to write `len(fps)`?

Comment: I've got some trouble installing OpenBabel. What error do you get when doing this? Maybe `__len__()` is undefined for `x.calcfp()`-elements...

Comment: Error is : object of type 'fingerprint' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

You can use function **fp** for fingerprint object. By default FP2 fingerprint is calculated, its length is 32.
There is code, which output length and bit-0

```
import pybel
smiles = ['CCCC', 'CCCN']
mols = [pybel.readstring("smi", x) for x in smiles]
fps = [x.calcfp() for x in mols]
print len(fps[0].fp)
print fps[0].fp[0]
```

Result:

```
32 
0
```